# Cannot figure out how to save this field into database

Tags: java, android

Me da el siguiente error:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

Voy a la línea que me marca y tengo esto:

```
public Ingrediente ingredientesreceta;
```

Ingrediente es una clase con sus atributos, y lo que quiero es que los ingredientes de la receta queden almacenados en un objecto de tipo Ingrediente, que ya lo tengo creado.

El código de esta clase es el siguiente:

```
package com.example.javie.myapplication.Entities;

import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.List;

@Entity(tableName = "ingredientes")
public class Ingrediente {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int idingrediente;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nombreingrediente")
    private String nombreingrediente;


    public Ingrediente(String nombreingrediente) {
        this.nombreingrediente = nombreingrediente;
    }

    public int getIdingrediente() {
        return idingrediente;
    }

    public void setIdingrediente(int idingrediente) {
        this.idingrediente = idingrediente;
    }

    public String getNombreingrediente() {
        return nombreingrediente;
    }

    public void setNombreingrediente(String nombreingrediente) {
        this.nombreingrediente = nombreingrediente;
    }

}


}
```

Estoy utilizando la librería **`Room`** y me salta el Error del título. Perdón si existen errores en cuando a la subida de artículos, es mi segundo post en este foro. Gracias.

Comment: Un bean debe tener un constructor sin parámetros (luego puedes añadir otros, pero el constructor sin parámetros debe existir); no sé si es necesario que sea público. Prueba a añadir *public Ingrediente() {}*

Comment: Probado y nada, me salta el mismo error a la hora de almacenar en la base de datos. Gracias!

Comment: Es una lista de ingredientes? osea un List<Ingrediente>?

Comment: Perdón, estaba pensando en JPA (que también tiene *entities*) y no me había fijado que estás usando Android.

Comment: @Jeylou revisa bien el LogCat, la linea que indicas es un objeto pero un atributo de este objeto estas agregando un tipo de valor incorrecto, revisa y agrega el error especifico.

Comment: Te hace falta compartirnos la clase Receta si es que la tienes

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema viene desde que Room no soporta directamente relaciones, pero para lograr esto nos da la opción de utilizar @ForeignKey. Entiendo que dentro de "Receta" tienes una lista de "Ingredientes" (Relación de uno a muchos) y posiblemente en el código tengas algo parecido a esto :

```
public class Receta {
    List<Ingrediente> ingredientes;
}
```

Puedes eliminar "List ingredientes;" y en tu clase "Ingrediente" agregar @ForeignKey con sus parámetros necesarios para poder tener la relación uno a muchos entre la receta y los ingredientes;

Algunos enlaces:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1